# home directory not created

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, user

I have created user by "useradd " the user created and created password using "passwd" command and able to login as newuser but while it type "cd" it says /home/newuser no file or directory found.

Anyone guide I need to manually create new directory every time I add user on that specific username?

Comment: Did you use the `-m` flag with useradd? Like: `useradd -m -s /bin/bash username`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MAN useradd/adduser](https://linux.die.net/man/8/useradd):

> -d, --home HOME_DIR
>       The new user will be created using HOME_DIR as the value for the user's login directory. The default is to append the LOGIN name to BASE_DIR and use that as the login directory name. The directory HOME_DIR does not have to exist but will not be created if it is missing.

Alternatively check how `adduser` behaves on your system. You can usually ask them for information on how they work by using `--help` or similar as the parameter.

Check [Create the home directory while creating a user [duplicate]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/393463/create-the-home-directory-while-creating-a-user). If you're running a debian flavor `adduser` and `useradd` are different things. Check their parameters individually on your system.